# How do I make my site return to its original seed data in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am following a tutorial but I had to delete some entities to make some tests.
I have the data in a class:

```
public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MusicStoreEntities>
{
    protected override void Seed(MusicStoreEntities context)
    {
       // Data
    }
}
```

But I am not sure how to make the site return to its original seed data in MVC. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

make it:

```
public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseAlways
```

to drop the database and recreate it. Turn it back afterwards. Or better still you can drop the database directly from SQLEXPRESS (or whichever DB provider you use) if you know how to. You don't need to do all this then.